# How to avoid Table Locks while Inserting Data in table

Tags: sql-server, insert, deadlock

In our application we are inserting records in 15 tables in a transaction from C# code.
For this we are creating one insert statement for each table, and append all in one query and use 'ExecuteNonQuery' to insert records in table. Because, we want insert to happen in all table and don't want any inconsistent data, we are using it in a transaction.

This functionality is written in a service and more than once service (same services, different installations) perform this task (inserting data into tables) concurrently.
These services are inserting totally different rows in tables and not in any way dependent.

But, when we are running these services we are getting deadlocks on these insert statements.

The code is like this:

1. Open DB Connection
2. Begin Transaction
3. Insert data in tables
4. Commit Transaction.

All services perform these steps on different set of data going in same 15 tables.

SQL Profiler trace suggests there are exclusive locks on these tables while insert.

Can you please suggest why it should be having table level locks while just firing insert statement on table and ending in deadlocks. And what is the best possible way to prevent it.

Comment: see this http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/deadlocks/

Comment: Do you still get the locking when you do not use the transaction?

Comment: A SQL Server transaction or .net? If .net, show us the code please

Answer (score 2):

You do not get deadlocks just from locking tables, even exclusive locking. If the tables are locked the new inserts will just wait for the existing inserts to finish (assuming you are not using a `no wait` hint).

Deadlocks happen when you lock resources in such a way that the sql statements cannot continue. Look for unbounded sub selects or where clauses that are not specific enough in your insert statements.

Post your sql so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: You could do. A circular wait can still happen if transaction A gets an X lock on T1, transaction B gets an X lock on T2. B requests an X lock on T1 and A requests one on T2.

Comment: Martin, that is what I was trying to say. Locking A, B, C in one session and then A, B, C in another session will not cause a deadlock, just a wait. Since user1047169 is using a single transaction and assuming the 15 inserts are always called in the same order he should not have a circular reference issue like you get when inserts are being made from many sources.

Comment: There is no reason to assume they are called in the same order as there is more than one service involved. The OP should really post the deadlock graph.

Comment: The way I read his question; he is calling multiple instances of the same service. Posting a deadlock graph would cetrainly help.

Comment: Actually, Just reread the question and I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: Also, I just suffered from a deadlock issue that was solved by adding a more specific where clause. A sub select was looking at too many rows to find the one row that needed to be updated. Adding a more specific where clause solved my deadlock issue. I may be projecting that experience into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Yes, we are using multiple instances of same service and the 'inserts' happen in same order. There is no where clause in it, no sub queries. We are just preparing simple insert statements and executing it. The deadlock graph is having data specific to client, so I will try to make it dummy data and post back here.